# Unable to install "url" package in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to install a "url" package in pycharm. But when installing I am getting error.
I have installed Microsoft visualC++ and 'wheel' package too now. Please help. What else I can do to install it. Thanks.

```
   > Collecting url
  Using cached url-0.4.2.tar.gz (140 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Collecting six (from url)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: url
  Building wheel for url (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for url (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for url
  Failed to build url

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [17 lines of output]
  Building from C++
  C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project1\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: 
  SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!
           
            ********************************************************************************
          Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
          versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.
  
          By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
          or your builds will no longer be supported.
  
          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for 
  details.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build 
  Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for url
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for url, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based 
  projects
```

please help

Heading

Answer (score 0):

Although you have installed Microsoft Visual C++, there's a strong possibility that it is not updated. I recommend installing version of the tool through this [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) and go through the download process through the 'download build tools' button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).